# Integrate Passbook App in my iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, passbook

In my iPhone application there is a list of gift coupons. I need to add coupons to the Passbook. How can I do this ?!

How to generate passes for each coupon?!

Is there any way to generate this pass dynamically?!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that by 'dynamically' you mean on-the-fly from within the app. The short answer is no.

Passes must include a signature which is a composition of a certificate provided by apple that is signed with your private key. From a security standpoint it is a terrible idea to include this information in your app, and as a result if Apple thinks you are signing passes from inside your app they will likely reject it from the app store.

This being the case, passes must be created and distributed by a server.

You should check out the [Passbook Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/PassKit_PG.pdf). This is a dense document, so it might be useful to start with the [Passbook Ecosystem Design](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Ecosystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH3-SW1)